# Arithmetic substitution in vi

Tags: unix, vi

I have an ascii file I need to edit in vi editor with numbers like this (space delimited):

```
   2.340   2.310   2.440   3.220   5.650   1.212
   2.310   2.350   2.640   3.420   2.651   8.232
   2.350   2.320   2.430   3.460   7.642   0.222

   ............
   ............
   ............
```

etc

I need to add a constant value 0.13 to every number above to give the following results

```
   2.470   2.440   2.570   3.350   5.780   1.342
   2.440   2.480   2.770   3.550   2.781   8.362
   2.480   2.450   2.560   3.590   7.772   0.352

   ............
   ............
   ............
```

etc

Question:
Does anyone have any idea how to do this replacement in vi editor?
:%s/.......

Answer (score 0):

`vi` is not the tool for your requirement.  Use `awk` instead:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){$i+=0.13}}i' file > file.modified
```

Which yields the following:

```
2.47 2.44 2.57 3.35 5.78 1.342 2.44 2.48 2.77 3.55 2.781 8.362 2.48 2.45 2.56 3.59 7.772 0.352
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. It works except for the output file which does not retain the original and preferred 3 decimal places for all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vim quite easily as the following:

```
:1,$ s/\(\d*\.\d*\)/\=str2float(submatch(1))+0.13/g
```

which directly answers the OP's question.